# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class HttpUTrace {
    
    public String result {set;get;}
    public Map<String ,String> resMap {set;get;}
    public String ipaddress {set;get;}
    
    public void traceMe()
    {
        Http h=new Http();
        HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();
        String ep='http://xml.utrace.de/?query='+ipaddress;
        request.setEndPoint(ep);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response=h.send(request);
        result=response.getBody();
        DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
        doc.load(result);
        DOM.XMLNode root=doc.getRootElement();//Results
        List<Dom.XMLNode> child=root.getChildElements();//Result
        List<Dom.XMLNode> subChild=child[0].getChildElements();
        for(Dom.XMLNode d:subChild)
        {
          resMap.put(d.getName(),d.getText());
        } 
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="HttpUTrace">
    <apex:form >
        <br/><br/><apex:inputText value="{!ipaddress}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Trace" action="{!traceMe}"/><br/><br/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Result" rendered="{! !ISNULL(result)}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!resMap}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a}" headerValue="Header"/>
                <apex:column value="{!resMap[a]}" HeaderValue="Value"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! It's great that you included enough code for me to come up with a resolution, but in the future, you should include as much information as possible, such as the line of code where the error came from. Please read about [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the map:

```
resMap = new Map<String, String>();
```

You need to do this before attempting to use it.

Comment: i declared outside the method ,is it wrong ?
 public Map<String ,String> resMap {set;get;}

Comment: @GaddamShivaranjan no,  since you need the variable in the page, it's in the right area. You just need to initialize an object before you can use it.

Comment: thx for the response